# Swift Code ending during variable set

Tags: database, swift, variables, parse-platform

I have the following code, and for some reason when it gets to the line

let num = data[pagesLeft]

The code just stops, and I cant figure out why. It's not a fatal error or anything, it just ends like the code execution is complete. Any ideas why it would be doing that?

I have the data variable at the top level for access and when I print it, it looks right to me.

```
func passData (passData : [ScheduleObject]) {
    data = passData
    print(passData.count)
    print(data)
    updateTemplate()
}

func updateTemplate() {
    pagesLeft = data.count
    print(pagesLeft)
    let num = data[pagesLeft]

    let weekObj = num.weekObj
    weekObj.fetchInBackground()

    customerName.text! = num.customerName
    address.text! = num.customerAddress
    phoneNumber.text! = num.customerPhone
    openingWeek.text! = GlobalFunctions().stringFromDateShortStyle(weekObj.weekStart) + " " + GlobalFunctions().stringFromDateShortStyle(weekObj.weekEnd)
    if num.confirmedDate != nil {
        openingDate.text! = GlobalFunctions().stringFromDateShortStyle(num.confirmedDate!)
    } else {
        openingDate.text! = "NOT CONFIRMED"
    }
    if num.confirmedWith != nil {
        confirmedWith.text! = num.confirmedWith!
    } else {
        confirmedWith.text! = "NOT CONFIRMED"
    }
    typeOfWinterCover.text! = num.coverType
    itemLocation.text! = num.locEssentials
    if (num.bringChem) {
        bringChemicals.text! = "Yes"
    } else {
        bringChemicals.text! = "No"
    }
    if (num.takeTrash) {
        takeTrash.text = "Yes"
    } else {
        takeTrash.text = "No"
    }
    notes.text = num.notes!
    accountNumber.text! = num.accountNumber!


    if (firsRun) {
        createPdfFromView(theView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName: "POC")
        firsRun = false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `let num = data[pagesLeft]` where `pagesLeft = data.count`, you're automatically out of the index range of `data`.

The last index of an array `x` is always `x.count - 1`.

Comment: Ah duh! It caught be off because it wasn't saying out of index with a fatal error, usually it does for me. Thank you!

Comment: No problems, and don't forget to upvote/mark as answered!